# extract an array from text file in php

Tags: php, arrays, text, foreach

How can I extract array from txt file.

I use file_put_contents to put array in to the text file.

```
  Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AMDSempron 145
        [1] => 860,000
        [2] => 910,000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelCore 2 Quad Q8200 2.33GHz 4MB L2 Cache
        [1] => 1,800,000
        [2] => 1,800,000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelCore i7-920 Processor (8M Cache, 2.66 GHz, 4.80 GT/s
        [1] => 3,300,000
        [2] => 3,300,000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelCoreâ¢ i5-3450 Processor -6M Cache, up to 3.50 GHz
        [1] => 5,600,000
        [2] => 6,800,000
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelÂ® Coreâ¢ i3-530 Processor  -4M Cache, 2.93 GHz
        [1] => 2,350,000
        [2] => 2,380,000
    )
  }
```

Then inputing array to text file.

This

file.txt

```
    Array
   (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AMDSempron 145
        [1] => 860,000
        [2] => 910,000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelCore 2 Quad Q8200 2.33GHz 4MB L2 Cache
        [1] => 1,800,000
        [2] => 1,800,000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelCore i7-920 Processor (8M Cache, 2.66 GHz, 4.80 GT/s
        [1] => 3,300,000
        [2] => 3,300,000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelCoreâ¢ i5-3450 Processor -6M Cache, up to 3.50 GHz
        [1] => 5,600,000
        [2] => 6,800,000
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => IntelÂ® Coreâ¢ i3-530 Processor  -4M Cache, 2.93 GHz
        [1] => 2,350,000
        [2] => 2,380,000
    )
  }
```

Now How Can I extracting?
I writed this code.

```
     <?php
    file_put_contents('array.txtl', print_r($data, TRUE));

    $arrtxt = file_get_contents('array.txt',treu);

    //Select Name and Price from array

    $par1= array_column( $arrtxt, 0);
    $par2 = array_column( $arrtxt, 1);

    //Combine Name and Price array
    $c = array_combine($par1, $par2);

    foreach($c as $name=>$price){
        echo 'Name:'.'&nbsp;'.$name.'<br />'.'<hr>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'price:'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$price.'<br />'.'<hr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
      ?>
```

but give thise error:

array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given in C:\wamp\www\curl\index.php on line 28

Comment: `file_get_contents` give you a String, not an Array.

Comment: Thank's . what Solution to get array from the text file?

Comment: I suggest you to save data as JSON using json_encode and then when you read data from file use json_decode. Then you will decode JSON in an array and you will be free to use it as an array

Comment: why dont you serialzie or json encode and write to file. read using file_get_contents and unserialize or json decode to get back the array?

Comment: I use thise code // file_put_contents('array.txt', print_r($data, TRUE));
$content = file_get_contents('array.txt');
$unserialized = unserialize($content); // but given problem //  Error at offset 0 of 5793 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code:

```
file_put_contents('array.txt', json_encode($data));

$arrtxt = file_get_contents('array.txt');
$newarr = json_decode($arrtxt);

print_r($newarr); //this will output an array
```

Comment: Thank's. one question :  with use the json_encode, decode will datas are an array in text file?

Comment: ok.// when I used jsin_decode extract data but what this character Ã¢Â„Â¢ .. How fix these?

Comment: What exactly was your input for encode and output after decode?

Comment: IntelCore\u00e2\u0084\u00a2 i5-3450 Processor -6M Cache

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your text file somewhat (note that the name of PHP's array-creating array() function is all-lower-case):

```
 <?php
 $myArray = array([0] => array([0] => AMDSempron 145
                               [1] => 860,000
                               [2] => 910,000
                              )
                  [1] => array([0] => IntelCore 2 Quad Q8200 2.33GHz 4MB L2 Cache
                               [1] => 1,800,000
                               [2] => 1,800,000
                              )
                  [2] => array([0] => IntelCore i7-920 Processor (8M Cache, 2.66 GHz, 4.80 GT/s
                               [1] => 3,300,000
                               [2] => 3,300,000
                              )
                  [3] => array([0] => IntelCore i5-3450 Processor -6M Cache, up to 3.50 GHz
                               [1] => 5,600,000
                               [2] => 6,800,000
                              )
                  [4] => array([0] => IntelCore i3-530 Processor  -4M Cache, 2.93 GHz
                               [1] => 2,350,000
                               [2] => 2,380,000
                              )
                 );
 ?>
```

Then, in the php file where you want to use this array-of-arrays, simply do this:

```
include("array.txt");
```

and "$myArray" will exist everywhere after that "include", and already BE the array.

Comment: By the way, because of the php tags inside the file, I THINK you don't have to rename the file to "array.php", but I might be mistaken.